# Batch Renaming regardless of file extension

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

I'm pretty new to batch renaming and I've looked around a bit and I have found some stuff on renaming lots of files that are all the same type but nothing really on renaming a bunch of files that have different extensions.

by this I mean I have a directory like so:

```
Folder 
  |
  file.jpg
  EBUFEWO.png
  otherFile.jpg
```

and I'm trying to figure out how I can rename it to be like this:

```
Folder
  |
  Renamed_0001.jpg
  Renamed_0002.png
  Renamed_0003.jpg
```

I'd like to retain the extensions of the files in the folder but rename them like I have above here.

I've been looking for a while and haven't really come across any example of this, any help would be great!

Comment: This will probably get moved out of askUbuntu. Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086502/rename-multiple-files-in-unix

Comment: @BenjaminBrink [That SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086502/rename-multiple-files-in-unix) is a useful resource, thanks! However, note that questions like this are [fully on-topic for Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/47/how-do-we-tell-if-a-question-belongs-here-or-rather-at-stackoverflow-superuser) and [network-wide policy is that such questions are *not* pushed off to other sites](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/).

Comment: @Eliah_Kagan Excellent. I just witnessed a case where the question was transferred.  Glad to see others think it belongs here, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd do

```
shopt -s nullglob

cd Folder

n=1
for file in *.*; do 
  printf -v newfile 'Renamed_%04d.%s' $((n++)) "${file##*.}"
  echo mv -- "$file" "$newfile"
done
mv -- EBUFEWO.png Renamed_0001.png
mv -- file.jpg Renamed_0002.jpg
mv -- otherFile.jpg Renamed_0003.jpg
```

(`echo` added for testing purposes). Alternatively, with the perl-based `prename`

```
cd Folder
prename -n 'our $n; s/(.*)\.(.*)$/sprintf "Renamed_%04d.%s", ++$n, $2/e' *.*
EBUFEWO.png renamed as Renamed_0001.png
file.jpg renamed as Renamed_0002.jpg
otherFile.jpg renamed as Renamed_0003.jpg
```

(`-n` added for testing purposes).

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver this worked just like I needed it to! also thanks for an additional bit for prename I'll have to check it out(never used prename)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```
count=1; \
for file in * ; do ext=${file##*.}; \
while [ ${#count} -ne 3 ]; do count="0"$count; done; \
mv "$file" Renamed_$count.$ext; count=$((10#$count+1)); done
```

This was tested on the contents of a single folder and performed as you specified.

1. `ext=${file##*.}`  getting extension of the file to be renamed.
2. `while [ ${#count} -ne 3 ]; do count="0"$count; done` you requested that the renamed files hold 3 digits this adds the required number of leading zeros, `1` becomes `001` and `20` becomes `020` etc
3. `mv "$file" Renamed_$count.$ext;` renames the file to the parameters specified.

Given my limited experience I am sure there are simpler more efficient methods.

Note that this was executed on a specified folder once.

Comment: at first it works but once it reached 008 I get a error

`-bash: ((: 008: value too great for base (error token is "008")`

Comment: my bad ... I have made the necessary adjustments ..